# South African Mobile Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm writing a simple mobile number validator in Javascript but cannot get the regex working correctly.

South African mobile numbers currently are set to:

- Start 0
- [678] (1 digit)
- [0-9] (1 digit)
- [0-9] (7 digits)

So example 0821234567 but people may also enter it as 082 123 4567 (with spaces or another way). I want to use regex to test as appose to just checking for numeric as I found 082123456d would also come back as valid.

Here is my sample function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function regex(number) {
            var regex = /0[678]\d[0-9]\d[0-9]{7,}\d/g;
            if (regex.test(number) === true) {
                console.log("work");
            } else {
                console.log("no");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: The easiest way to validate phone numbers, in my opinion, is to just do `.replace(/\D/g,'')` to strip out anything non-numeric, and see if the rest is valid. Also, make sure to use `^` and `$` at the start and end, respectively, to stop the `082123456d` thing.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you should have put that as an answer.That actually is the best solution

Comment: What's so special about that first 0-9 that it should be evaluated separately from the next 7 digits? can't you just do `[0-9] (8 digits)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var number = '0821234568'; //082123456d or 082 123 4567

var trimmed = number.replace(/\s/g, '');

var regex = /^0(6|7|8){1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$/;

if (regex.test(trimmed) === true) {
    console.log("work");
else
    console.log("no");
```